Building llvm-gbz80 on Windows
I'm trying to compile LLVM IR to (gb)z80 code. I tried several github repositories that do this:

https://github.com/grapereader/llvm-z80
https://github.com/Bevinsky/llvm-gbz80
https://github.com/Bevinsky/llvm-gbz80

I cloned them and now, I have to build them. I don't really know anything about CMake, so I just tried cmake .. This resulted in the same error message in all three:
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.21.3/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/c++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /c/Users/armin/programming/gameboy/llvm/llvm-z80_2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make.exe -f Makefile cmTC_3c0ee/fast && /usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3c0ee.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3c0ee.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/armin/programming/gameboy/llvm/llvm-z80_2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3c0ee.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /usr/bin/c++.exe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3c0ee.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /c/Users/armin/programming/gameboy/llvm/llvm-z80_2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    c++: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1plus': spawn: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3c0ee.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_3c0ee.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/armin/programming/gameboy/llvm/llvm-z80_2/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    make: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_3c0ee/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

I googled what I can do and found this answer. However, I don't know where to paste that line. I tried to paste it above the project() line (as recommended in the post) in the CMakeLists.txt file in all three repositories but the error remained.
How can I use LLVM to build gbz80 or how can I build those projects?

As far as I understand, you are configuring your project for MinGW. The problem is about your C++ compiler. Probably, you haven't installed it in that environment, or your installation is incomplete.
